# Add node degree to node label in networkx

Tags: python, attributes, nodes, networkx

I want to add the degree of each node to the label of that node. If foo has degree 1 I would want the label to be foo-1. I have tried `nx.set_node_attributes(G, G.degree(), 'label')` but that doesn't change the label and even if it would I guess it would replace the label rather than adding the degree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve it using `nx.relabel_nodes` in a `for` loop. It ain't pretty but it works.

```
    for node in G.nodes():
    d = G.degree(node)
    mapping = {node: node + ' - ' + str(d)}
    G = nx.relabel_nodes(G, mapping)
```